# I am facing npm install issue in VS code

Tags: node.js, npm

qasimnoman@Qasims-MacBook-Pro ~ % npm install
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /Users/qasimnoman/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/qasimnoman/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/qasimnoman/.npm/_logs/2022-04-08T12_59_39_855Z-debug-0.log

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have no `package.json` in your current directory.

Are you in the right directory ?

Comment: I made a new directory and cd directory then write this

Comment: Please make sure your directory has actually the file `ls package.json`. if not you maybe want to create a new one with `npm init` or change the directory to a project which already has been initialized.